# Tomcat crashes after setting environment for Jacoco Agent

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, code-coverage, remote-debugging, jacoco

I have a simple Spring boot application having some REST API's exposed.
I want to test the coverage for code by calling the these rest endpoints from of my testcases, below are the constraints for me:

1. The application is running on a remote machine, inside tomcat.
2. My prefered way is to use Jacoco to generate the coverage report
   with maven-surefire or maven-failsafe plugins.

Currently, I'm trying to attach jacoco agent to Tomcat (where my application is deployed).
Below are the variables that I'm setting in setenv file in tomcat:

```
SET JACOCO= -javaagent:"C:\packages\jars\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.jar"=destfile="C:\jacoco.exec",append=true,includes=* 
SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %JACOCO%
```

But, when I try to start tomcat with this configuration it crashes without any logs, can anyone suggest any other way to generate the coverage for remotely running application?

Comment: First of all - version 0.7.5 is 3 years old and for example doesn't support Java > 8, so upgrade to the latest one, which as of today is 0.8.2. And in any case you'd better find logs or watch out console output to find reasons why tomcat doesn't start.

Comment: @Godin Yes I need to try with the latest version of jacocoagent, but tomcat doesn't have any logs generated or crash report as such.